# supportedInterfaceOrientation not working

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two viewController, So I want the first viewController can rotate all side and second viewController can rotate left side only. And this is my code in second viewController.
Thank you very much.

```
-(NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

Comment: are you using in ios5 or ios6?

Comment: are you using navigationController?

Comment: Yes I using navigationController and Tab-bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using navigationController,
Create a category like this,

```
  @interface UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

    @end

    @implementation UINavigationController (Rotation_IOS6)

    -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
    {
        if([self.visibleViewController isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"SecondViewController")])
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft
        }
        return NO;
    }

    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
    {
        return [[self topViewController] supportedInterfaceOrientations];
    }

    - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    {
        if([self.visibleViewController isMemberOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"SecondViewController")])
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft
        }
        return [[self.viewControllers lastObject] preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
    }

@end
```

Comment: you need to create New File -> ObjectiveCCategory -> Category on UINavigationController

Comment: So if I using UITabBarController, How I coding?

Comment: same thing only. ios6 orientation not affecting tabbarcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldRotateToOrientation:(UIDeviceOrientation)orientation {
  if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
    return NO;
  }
  else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    return NO;
  }
 else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
    return NO;
  }
 else if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
    return YES;
  }
}
```

//Use this method to check which orientation going to execute and you can return no if you 
//want to stop orientation and if you return yes then orientation execute

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the category of NavigationController

Declare that bool in AppDelegate to used in all over projcet.

Declare property  AppDelegate.h

```
@property BOOL * islandscape;
```

AppDelegate.m file

@synthesize islandscape;

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface UINavigationController (orientation1)

@end
```

.M File

```
#import "UINavigationController+orientation1.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (orientation1)

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{

    AppDelegate * delegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    if (delegate.islandscape)
    {
        // for iPhone, you could also return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

@end
```

and then used that bool varible in SeconViewController.

```
delegate.islandscape=Yes;
```

Comment: app deleagte is used declaere bool varible in AppDelegate.h

Comment: delegate.islandscape it Error.

Comment: delegate.islandscape=YES; I code in SecondViewController.m,Right?

Comment: so what's the problem now this code works fine for you. if this answer help a littel more then accept this answer. becauser other can take referance from that answer..